# Django oauth2 request.user returns AnonymousUser

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I'm a Django newbie and am trying to create an API to the backend for use by iOS client. Currently I am testing my API access with curl.

I have successfully generated access tokens using:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=example_user&password=example_password" http://clientID:clientSecret@localhost:8000/o/token/
```

which generated the following response -

```
{
    "access_token": "oAyNlYuGVk1Sr8oO1EsGnLwOTL7hAY", 
    "scope": "write read", 
    "expires_in": 36000, 
    "token_type": "Bearer", 
    "refresh_token": "pxd5rXzz1zZIKEtmqPgE608a4H9E5m"
}
```

I then used the access token to try to access the following class view:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from oauth2_provider.views.generic import ProtectedResourceView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class post_test(ProtectedResourceView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.user)
        return JsonResponse({'Message': "You used a GET request"})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.user)
        return JsonResponse({'Message': 'You used a POST request'})

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(post_test, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

with the following curl request:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer oAyNlYuGVk1Sr8oO1EsGnLwOTL7hAY" -X GET http://localhost:8000/api/post-test/
```

Which properly responds to the client with:

```
{"Message": "You used a GET request"}
```

But in the console, where I expect the `request.user` variable, I get `AnonymousUser`.

Isn't the token supposed to be assigned to `example_user`? Shouldn't that be what `request.user` returns?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this one?

Comment: Nope unfortunately. For now, I'm using a work around: inserting the username in the POST and GET parameter list.

Comment: @jhc, do you still use a workaround? Did you finally find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

`request.user` is returning `AnonymousUser` because the access token you have used here is not associated with any user
From the Docs it says:
When you do generate the access token using the `/o/token/` endpoint, it doesn't automatically link the token with a user. It only verifies the provided credentials and generates the access token if the credentials are true and valid. The token itself doesn't carry information about the whom is the user.

Use `Django REST Framework` after you install it, then add the Auth in the attributes field:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

run: `python manage.py drf_create_token <the user name heree>`

Now for the view `post_test`:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from django.http import JsonResponse

class post_test(APIView):
    auth_cls = [TokenAuthentication]
    perm_cls = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        print(user) 
        return JsonResponse({'Message': "You used a GET request"})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        print(user)
        return JsonResponse({'Message': 'You used a POST request'})
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your exact snippets and it worked on my end. I can get the user with `request.user`.

You are most likely missing a few configs, specifically the `Middleware` and `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

> ```
> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
>     'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
>     # Uncomment following if you want to access the admin
>     #'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
>     '...',
> ]
>
> MIDDLEWARE = [
>     '...',
>     # If you use AuthenticationMiddleware, be sure it appears before OAuth2TokenMiddleware.
>     # AuthenticationMiddleware is NOT required for using django-oauth-toolkit.
>     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>     'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
>     '...',
> ]
> ```

You can read more information here:
https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_03.html

Let me know if it still does not work and I'll revisit the snippets once again.

Answer (score -1):

Use `request.resource_owner` instead of `request.user`.

The Django OAuth Toolkit makes a distinction between the user associated with a bearer token and the user associated with any other Django authentication that might be attached to the request. Specifically, the `ProtectedResourceView` includes behavior from the [`ProtectedResourceMixin`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/views/mixins.py#L197-L213), which includes the following dispatch method:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # let preflight OPTIONS requests pass
    if request.method.upper() == "OPTIONS":
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # check if the request is valid and the protected resource may be accessed
    valid, r = self.verify_request(request)
    if valid:
        request.resource_owner = r.user
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: I have the same issue, and this doesn't fix it